# Problem installing neo4j.py

Tags: python, neo4j, python-install, neo4j.py

I have followed the instructions [here](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j.py/snapshot/) and for some reason I am getting the following traceback:

```
root@ubuntu:~/Downloads/neo4j-python# python setup.py install

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 146, in <module>
    main()
  File "setup.py", line 134, in main
    args[attr] = pom[attr]
  File "/home/omer/Downloads/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 58, in __getitem__
    element)
  File "/home/omer/Downloads/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 57, in <lambda>
    return self.pattern.sub(lambda match:self[match.groupdict()['var']],
  File "/home/omer/Downloads/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 54, in __getitem__
    element = self.parent[path]
  File "/home/omer/Downloads/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 91, in __getitem__
    return replacement.get(path, lambda s,x:x)(self, self.__pom[path])
  File "/home/omer/Downloads/neo4j-python/pom.py", line 56, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(path)
KeyError: 'project.artifactId'
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? I am running ubuntu 11.04 and python 2.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on [serverfualt](https://serverfault.com/questions/233212/unable-to-install-neo4j-python-on-jython2-5-1-keyerror-project-artifactid).
See the issue [here](https://trac.neo4j.org/ticket/302).